# Deserialize 2 types of XML using Polymorphism OOP principals

Tags: c#, oop, xml-parsing, polymorphism, xml-deserialization

I have 2  types of xml I would like to **deserialize** into an object.
Part of their structure is similar. I've tried to use OO Polymorphism principal - by using the
virtual + new combination, in order to make it as useable as possible, but I still can't figure out how to do it.
Here is a demonstration - You can see that the difference is in the **MSGDATA** node.

TYPE 1 XML:

```
<MESSAGE>
    <DOCUMENT>
        <MSGHDR>
            <TIME_STAMP>2020010100:00:00.000</TIME_STAMP>
            <MESSAGE_NAME>1</MESSAGE_NAME>
        </MSGHDR>
        <MSGDATA>
            <ITEMSTYPE_1>
                <ITEMTYPE_1>
                    <NAME_OF_TYPE_1>TYPE1_AAAA</NAME_OF_TYPE_1>
                </ITEMTYPE_1>
                <ITEMTYPE_1>
                    <NAME_OF_TYPE_1>TYPE1_BBBB</NAME_OF_TYPE_1>
                </ITEMTYPE_1>
            </ITEMSTYPE_1>
        </MSGDATA>
    </DOCUMENT>
    <DOCUMENT>
        <MSGHDR>
            <TIME_STAMP>2020010100:00:00.000</TIME_STAMP>
            <MESSAGE_NAME>2</MESSAGE_NAME>
        </MSGHDR>
        <MSGDATA>
            <ITEMSTYPE_1>
                <ITEMTYPE_1>
                    <NAME_OF_TYPE_1>TYPE1_EEEEEE</NAME_OF_TYPE_1>
                </ITEMTYPE_1>
                <ITEMTYPE_1>
                    <NAME_OF_TYPE_1>TYPE1_FFFFF</NAME_OF_TYPE_1>
                </ITEMTYPE_1>
            </ITEMSTYPE_1>
        </MSGDATA>
    </DOCUMENT>
</MESSAGE>
```

TYPE 2 XML:

```
<MESSAGE>
    <DOCUMENT>
        <MSGHDR>
            <TIME_STAMP>2020010100:00:00.000</TIME_STAMP>
            <MESSAGE_NAME>1</MESSAGE_NAME>
        </MSGHDR>
        <MSGDATA>
            <ITEMSTYPE_2>
                <ITEMTYPE_2>
                    <NAME_OF_TYPE_2>TYPE2_CCCC</NAME_OF_TYPE_2>
                </ITEMTYPE_2>
                <ITEMTYPE_2>
                    <NAME_OF_TYPE_2>TYPE2_DDDD</NAME_OF_TYPE_2>
                </ITEMTYPE_2>
            </ITEMSTYPE_2>
        </MSGDATA>
    </DOCUMENT>
</MESSAGE>
```

Here is the data structure (I demonstrate it only with TYPE1 XML) - pay attention to the relations between **Item_1_Message** and base class **ItemMessage** - they have the same property **Documents** - but of different types with inheritance relationship:

/*FIXED*/

```
[XmlRoot("MESSAGE")]
public abstract class ItemMessage
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual List<ItemDocument> Documents {get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("MESSAGE")]
public class Item_1_Message : ItemMessage
{
    [XmlElement("DOCUMENT)]
    public new List<Type_1_ItemDocument> Documents {get; set; }
}




[XmlRoot(ElementName="MSGHDR")]
public class MsgHeader
{
    [XmlElement("TIME_STAMP")]
    public string strTimeStamp {get; set;}
    
    [XmlElement("MESSAGE_NAME")]
    public string MessageName {get; set;}
}

[XmlRoot("DOCUMENT")]
public abstract class ItemDocument
{
    [XmlElement("MSGHDR")]
    public MsgHeader {get; set;}
}



/*This is related to TYPE1 XML*/
public class Type_1_ItemDocument : ItemDocument
{
    [XmlElement("MSGDATA)]
    public Type_1_ItemData itemData {get ; set; }
}


[XmlRoot(ElementName = "MSGDATA")]
public class Type_1_ItemData
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ITEMSTYPE_1")]
    public ItemsType_1 itemstype1 {get; set;}
}



[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ITEMSTYPE_1")]
public class ItemsType_1
{
    [Xmlelement("ITEMTYPE_1")]
    public List<Item1> items {get ; set;}
    
}


[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ITEMTYPE_1")]
public class Item1
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "NAME_OF_TYPE_1")]
    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string name {get;set;}
}
```

Now, to make a long story short, when I'm trying to deserialize it as shown below:

```
XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Item_1_Message));
var result = xmls.Deserialize(new StringReader(<The XML text>));
```

I get an exception of hiding the base class/

SOLUTION: on the abstract class virtual property - I replaced the XmlAttribute with an [XmlIgnore]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is already updated in the code: on the abstract class virtual property - I replaced the XmlAttribute with an [XmlIgnore]